# SharePoint 2013 List not saving changes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, list-form

I have a list in SharePoint 2013, every time I add a new item on the list it gets discarded, it shows as if its saving but when I check on the list, the item that I added is not available.

I can't add a new item at all, please help.

Comment: Is there any custom code added on list form? Is there any list/column validation formula added to list?

Comment: Is there a filter on the list? Please create a new list and compare the result.